# Merging release into master with no resulting diff

Tags: git, git-flow

At work we have a git workflow, based on git flow. We have 3 main branches: dev, release and master

Dev is what we are currently working on, master is what we have in production and release is when we are doing a release and making the last bug fixes. When the release is ready the release branch is merged into master and pushed into production.

Any hotfixes made in master are also pushed into dev (and the release branch (if currently running))

The question is now how we ensure that the code in the release branch is actually what is in master after the merge? Put in another way, there should be no diff between release and master (after the merge).

When merging into master from the release branch, we would also not want to deal with conflicts, so any of those should be handled automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid conflicts when merging into master you can use `git merge --ours' which ignores any changes in master that would conflict with changes in release, but that has the potential for problems when you have more than one stream of development.  For instance if you have support issues that fix the code in production (master) or if you have more than one release branch.

Merge conflicts are a package deal when working with branches; they will happen, just adjust your workflow to handle them in isolation to minimize any adverse impact.

To illustrate this, consider the scenario in which there is an existing version in production that has been bug-fixed and a release branch ready to be moved to production (merged to master).  It looks something like this:

```
master  -A---------E------G
          \   \   /      /
bug-fix    \   C-D      /
            \          /
release      B--*--*--F
```

In this, B & C are branched from A, E is the merge commit of commit D on **bug-fix** into **master** and G is the merge commit of commit F on **release** into **master**.

At G there can be merge conflicts if the same files have been changed in both **bug-fix** and **release**.  If `git merge --ours` has been used at G, the changes made at E can be lost.

A merge can be handled with by branching master and merging release into it, then rebasing this throwaway branch back onto master.  This should only be done if the process is well controlled, for instance with a single person designated to make all merges into master.

At this point, G will not be exactly like F, it will also include the changes introduced in the bug-fix commit at E.

It is also possible to merge **bug-fix** into **release** as well as **master**, which would make F and G the same again.  However, there is a best practice that says to *never merge down*.  This means, with the branches in the order laid out in the diagram (more stable on top), merges should always be from the lower branch into the upper branch.  This has two primary benefits, the first is that stable code is not merged into less stable code and branches stay *pure* in the sense they only contain the changes relevant to the feature they are introducing.  For instance, if D was merged into **release** it would need to be tested along with **release** and release then contains both the change-sets from the feature it is introducing and the change-set of the bug fix.

To prevent this from being a problem I always checkout the more stable branch, merge the less stable into it and go from there.

Also, note that `--ours` is the branch that is checked out, `--theirs` is the other branch being merged in.  When you change the direction of the merge, the changes they are referring to are swapped.

Comment: In git-flow however, up-merging is what you're supposed to do for hotfix branches. git flow is based on [A successful git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), which states exactly that. Hotfix branches are special concerning that, and I'm pretty sure that this is okay. Hotfixes are special already because you shouldn't change the master branch except by merging in a release normally. The same goes for release branches, which are merged back into develop after release (to push version numbers there and backport bugfixes from there).

Comment: Yes, the workflow I use began heavily influenced by that article.  I found over time, however, the tree becomes very convoluted when downward commits are allowed.  To clean up the tree and make the workflow easier to work with I followed the advise in the git workflow manual page section **Merging upwards** -- found here http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitworkflows.html.

Comment: To quote from there: *Always commit your fixes to the oldest supported branch that require them. Then (periodically) merge the integration branches upwards into each other.* This would require to put the hotfixes in release. This is not possible though, as they must go into master before the release, and you cannot merge release before the release cycle is done.

Comment: Maybe we have differing ideas on what a 'hot-fix' is.  A hot-fix for me is only required when some problem must be fixed outside the normal development cycle -- which indicates an issue in production that cannot (or should not) wait for the next release.  The oldest supported branch that needs a hot-fix is the branch that reflects production (master).  The section in the workflow manual also mentions cherry-picking when the change of a hot-fix is also needed in development -- cautioning it is _nothing to worry about unless you do it very frequently_.

Comment: We agree on our *hot-fix* ideas. So we would have to merge master into release before the release, if master is considered more „downwards“ than release? Sorry, I'm really not sure.

Comment: master is up (more stable) than release, so I merge release into master.  If I have reason to think it will not go smoothly I will create a temporary merge branch from master and merge release into it and then on up.  It's a work in progress, probably always will be, but it works better than any other way we've tried.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible for release and master be different after they are merged. Both branches point to the same commit, the merge commit tying the branches together. Thus they are exactly the same.

If you want to make sure the contents of the release branch become the contents of the master branch, you want to use the ours merge strategy. That ignores the changes in the master branch, and just results in nicely superceding the old history of the master branch. So you'd do

```
git checkout release
git pull --strategy=ours . master
```

Comment: I don't understand what "--strategy=ours ." means

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the "ours" merge strategy. As pointed out in [the git merge man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge), it will always use "our" side of the merge and ignore everything on "their" side. It explicitly mentions that this is used when one side completely supersedes the other.

Edit: Note that there is an "ours" strategy and an "ours" option for the "recursive" strategy. You want the former, the **strategy** and **not** the *strategy option*.